# In terminal under GUI session, <ESC>Oo produces "/" character

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, gnome

When in a GNOME3 GUI login session under Ubuntu 20.10, pressing `ESC`, `O`, `o` in quick succession in a terminal window produces a '/' character rather than entering those keystrokes.  This is problematic when running Vim where I often want to break out of Insert mode and quickly start a new line of text above the current one.

Other key sequences starting with `ESC` `O` behave similarly: `ESC` `O` `q` yields "1"; ...`w` a "7", etc.  Many also work as expected.

The time window for entering these keys and triggering the effect seems to be about 2 seconds while in Vim, and considerably shorter on the command line.

While in a console login via `CTRL` `ALT` `F6`, this behaviour is not observed.

It also does not occur in other apps like Chrome, Text Editor, or GVim.

It does occur under both Guake and Terminal.

I also observed the same behaviour in a WSL install of Ubuntu on a Windows 10 machine.  There do not seem to be any common configuration elements between the two home directories that are suspect.

I have not checked the behaviour under other desktops such as LXDE or KDE.

I have noticed that this problem does not occur in a MacOS terminal session.

Is this a feature of GNOME?  Is there some way to disable it or modify it?

Comment: Duplicate? https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/17192/macro-oendores-results-in-new-line-end2es-how

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in VTE's keymap, from [this change in 2014](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/vte/-/commit/598572b526568591ca91e3e0019412274edd9643):

> commit 598572b526568591ca91e3e0019412274edd9643
> Author: Egmont Koblinger egmont@gmail.com
> Date:   Sun May 18 13:36:01 2014 +0200
>
> keymap: Use hardcoded sequences instead of terminfo
>
> https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=728900#c5

The source code says this:

```
static const struct _vte_keymap_entry _vte_keymap_GDK_KP_Divide[] = {
        {cursor_all, keypad_default, 0, "/", 1},
        {cursor_all, keypad_app, VTE_NUMLOCK_MASK, "/", 1},
        {cursor_all, keypad_app, 0, _VTE_CAP_SS3 "o", -1},
        {cursor_all, keypad_all, 0, X_NULL, 0},
};
```

where *SS3* happens to be the <kbd>*Escape*</kbd><kbd>**`O`**</kbd> sequence.  Some terminals (and possibly some versions of gnome-terminal) allow keys to be redefined, but in a quick check of Ubuntu 20, I see only the ability to assign a binding to one of the *actions* that the terminal recognizes:

[image: gnome-terminal preferences]

If that route doesn't help, there are other terminals which run on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR Check to see your `timeoutlen` and/or `ttimeoutlen` vim options aren't too high.

This isn't specific to Gnome. I had a similar issue a while back, only it was <Esc>Or producing "2":

[Macro “oend^[Ores^[” results in new line “end2es”. How?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/17192/macro-oendores-results-in-new-line-end2es-how)

The terminal provides special keys (like <kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>-></kbd>) to the programs running under it as escape sequences. For vim to know whether to interpret these escape sequences or interpret each character on its own, it uses a timer to determine if the user likely typed them out or if the terminal provided the sequence as a translation to a special key (which should be much quicker than one could type). Vim documents this on the option `esckeys`:

```
'esckeys' 'ek'      boolean (Vim default: on, Vi default: off)
            global
    Function keys that start with an <Esc> are recognized in Insert
    mode.  When this option is off, the cursor and function keys cannot be
    used in Insert mode if they start with an <Esc>.  The advantage of
    this is that the single <Esc> is recognized immediately, instead of
    after one second.  Instead of resetting this option, you might want to
    try changing the values for 'timeoutlen' and 'ttimeoutlen'.  Note that
    when 'esckeys' is off, you can still map anything, but the cursor keys
    won't work by default.
    NOTE: This option is set to the Vi default value when 'compatible' is
    set and to the Vim default value when 'compatible' is reset.
    NOTE: when this option is off then the |modifyOtherKeys| functionality
    is disabled while in Insert mode to avoid ending Insert mode with any
    key that has a modifier.
```

To see this behavior under a default configuration of vim, you must be typing the 3 keys in under a tenth of a second.

Since you're seeing your time window in vim being 2 seconds, I would guess your `timeoutlen` and/or `ttimeoutlen` vim options are too high?

```
                        *'timeoutlen'* *'tm'*
'timeoutlen' 'tm'   number  (default 1000)
            global

                        *'ttimeoutlen'* *'ttm'*
'ttimeoutlen' 'ttm' number  (default -1, set to 100 in |defaults.vim|)
            global
    The time in milliseconds that is waited for a key code or mapped key
    sequence to complete.  Also used for CTRL-\ CTRL-N and CTRL-\ CTRL-G
    when part of a command has been typed.
    Normally only 'timeoutlen' is used and 'ttimeoutlen' is -1.  When a
    different timeout value for key codes is desired set 'ttimeoutlen' to
    a non-negative number.

        ttimeoutlen mapping delay      key code delay   ~
           < 0      'timeoutlen'       'timeoutlen'
          >= 0      'timeoutlen'       'ttimeoutlen'

    The timeout only happens when the 'timeout' and 'ttimeout' options
    tell so.  A useful setting would be >
        :set timeout timeoutlen=3000 ttimeoutlen=100
    (time out on mapping after three seconds, time out on key codes after
    a tenth of a second).
```

Now, `/` might not seem like a special key, but it's apparently meant to be interpreted differently from the one next to <kbd>Shift</kbd>. Looking at the manpage urxvt(7), I see:

```
KP_Divide      /       ESC O o
```

`KP` probably meaning the numeric keypad.